# FullCalendar - Create Event with Dropdown

Tags: html, fullcalendar, dropdown

Using FullCalendar 5.9.0, I attempt to include an HTML `select` dropdown within an event using the `eventContent` hook. I am unable to select the dropdown box within the event with a mouse. I can use the Tab key to put focus on the dropdown and the arrow keys to change the selected option.

I have reproduced the behavior at https://codepen.io/stevewillson/pen/eYRwMoz

Is there a way to allow a user to click a dropdown within an event?

Comment: This is likely to be an internal fullCalendar bug, you would need to report it (if it hasn't been already). See https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs . At stackoverflow we can't fix internal bugs, we can only help you with your implementation of fullCalendar and using its features.

Comment: Thanks, I filled a report: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/6580 . I see that there is a `mousedown` listener on element div.fc-timeline-body that when removed (manually through Chrome Dev Tools) allows selection of the dropdown, but when I remove the 'mousedown' event listener, then I am unable to drag or resize the event.

Comment: There is already an issue addressing this topic: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/5963